# Caddy Server Next.js 13 app static image file not serving. showing ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: next.js, caddy, caddyfile

I'm using next.js 13 app route.

Caddy file configuration:

```
my-domain.com {
        reverse_proxy http://localhost:3000
}
```

Next.js app log:

```
 cause: [Error: 0068BFE9207F0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:
  ] {
     library: 'SSL routines',
     reason: 'wrong version number',
     code: 'ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER'
  }
```

Tried with nginx Let's Encrypt ssl. It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by updating the next.js version. Now it's working fine.